# Is it possible to pass and retrieve a state in a quickcheck generator

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, quickcheck, state-monad

I would like to create a quickcheck generator to generate a data structure like a tree. Due to the specifics caracteristics of this structure I would like the value to be generated according to its depth in the structure and store tags generated at one place to reuse them at another place. So I would like to pass a state to my generators (like in the  with [State monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html) with `put` and `get`).

**Is there a function in the quickcheck library to do that or should I combine a [StateT](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html#t:StateT) monad with the [Gen](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.14.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Gen.html#t:Gen) monad ? Can [quickcheck-transformer](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/quickcheck-transformer) be a solution ?**

Comment: `StateT` sounds like a good option. `GenT` does not, unless you need state from generating one value to persist to the next (which would be *very* different).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to create a quickcheck generator with a state. This state can then be used to tweak the generators according to embedded values.

it requires the modules :

```
import           Control.Monad
import           Control.Monad.Trans.Class
import           Control.Monad.Trans.State
import           Test.QuickCheck
import           Test.QuickCheck.Gen
```

**Example**

Considering this data structure:

```
data MyElem = Header String
              | Upper [MyElem]
              | Str [String]
              | Tag String
              deriving(Show)
```

Suppose that we want to generate a random structure with a limited depth, beginning with a header and without duplicate tag.

We create the following state data structure:

```
data MyState = MyState
    { lastHeader :: Maybe String -- ^ The title of the last header (If a header is passed).
    , level      :: Int          -- ^ The level (depth) where we are in the structure.
    , usedTags   :: [String]     -- ^ The list of laready used tags.
    }

initState = MyState
    { lastHeader = Nothing
    , level = 1
    , usedTags = []
    }
```

We use the `StateT` modifier to create a state with the embedded `MyState` and with the inner `Gen` monad  (from the quickcheck library)

```
type MyGen t = StateT MyState Gen t
```

We can define generator with a state depending behavior for each elements of the `MyElem` data structure.
In these function, we will use the `lift` function to use `quickcheck` functions in top of the `MyGen` monad and retrieve their results.

```
genUpper :: MyGen MyElem
genUpper = do
    modify (\st -> st { level = level st + 1 })
    es <- genBase
    modify (\st -> st { level = level st - 1 })
    return $ Upper es


genElems :: MyGen [MyElem]
genElems = do
    l <- gets level
    if l == 1
        then vectorOfM 6 $ oneofM [genStr, genHeader, genUpper, genTag]
        else if l > 4 -- Limit the depth to 4
            then vectorOfM 3 $ oneofM [genStr, genTag]
            else vectorOfM 4 $ oneofM [genStr, genUpper, genTag]


genStr :: MyGen MyElem
genStr = do
    l <- gets level
    v <- lift $ case l of -- Set the maximum string length according to the level of the structure.
        1 -> choose (5, 10)
        2 -> choose (3, 7)
        _ -> choose (1, 5)
    s <- lift $ vectorOf v $ elements ["Lorem", "Ispum", "Dolor", "Sit", "Amet", "Elit", "Duis", "Sagittis", "Tortor"]
    return $ Str s

genHeader :: MyGen MyElem
genHeader = do
    h <- lift $ elements ["A header", "Another header", "Still another header", "No more header"]
    modify (\st -> st { lastHeader = Just h })
    return $ Header h

genTag :: MyGen MyElem
genTag = do
    tgs <- gets usedTags
    let tag = head $ filter (`notElem` tgs) $ map (\i -> "TAG" ++ show i) [1 ..]
    modify (\st -> st { usedTags = tag : usedTags st }) -- Set the already used tags
    return $ Tag tag


genBase = do
    stat <- get
    case lastHeader stat of
        Nothing -> do -- Force the first element to be a Header.
            e  <- genHeader
            es <- genBase
            return $ e : es

        Just _ -> do
            genElems
```

It is necessary to make specific versions of some transformers of the quickcheck library to make it work with the new monad `MyGen`.
You will have to rewrite some of the functions described in the source file [Test.QuickCheck.Gen](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.14.2/docs/src/Test.QuickCheck.Gen.html)

```
vectorOfM :: Int -> MyGen t -> MyGen [t]
vectorOfM = replicateM

oneofM :: [MyGen t] -> MyGen t
oneofM [] = error "oneofM used with empty list"
oneofM gs = do
    v <- lift $ choose (0, length gs - 1)
    gs !! v
```

Then you can use the new generator with both the `generate` and the `evalStateT` function.

```
main = do
    struct <- generate $ evalStateT genBase initState
    print struct
```